# Opportunities of Sharepoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, .net

Can I develop EventReceivers, TimerJobs, WebParts and different components in Sharepoint 2013 Foundation. If it can not, could you give me a link to approve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop Event Receivers, Timer Jobs and WebParts for SharePoint 2013 Foundation - as sandbox or farm solutions. However, you can't use "Business Data" and "OOTB Recommendations" Webparts as these are not available in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

I find this resource helpful when comparing SharePoint 2013 versions: https://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/